# Will @Transactional rollback if it fails before second transaction?

Tags: java, spring

Does Spring transaction management rollback operations that succeeded before it fails whether or not it failed during a database operation? For example:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PurchaseInvoiceLineServiceImpl implements PurchaseInvoiceLineService {

    @Autowired
    private PurchaseInvoiceLineRepository purchaseInvoiceLineRepository;
    @Autowired
    private StockRepository stockRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PurchaseInvoiceRepository purchaseInvoiceRepository;
    @Autowired
    private SupplierDebtRepository supplierDebtRepository;

    public <S extends PurchaseInvoiceLine> S save(S purchaseInvoiceLine) {
        purchaseInvoiceLineRepository.save(purchaseInvoiceLine);
        updatePurchaseInvoiceAmountForCreate(purchaseInvoiceLine);
        // update stock
        Stock stock = stockRepository.getStockByProduct(purchaseInvoiceLine.getProductId());
        stock.setQuantity(stock.getQuantity().add(purchaseInvoiceLine.getQuantity()));
        stockRepository.update(stock);
        // update debt
        PurchaseInvoice purchaseInvoice = purchaseInvoiceRepository.findOne(purchaseInvoiceLine.getPurchaseInvoiceId());
        SupplierDebt supplierDebt = supplierDebtRepository.getDebtBySupplierId(purchaseInvoice.getSupplierId());
        supplierDebt.setAmount(supplierDebt.getAmount().add(purchaseInvoiceLine.getLineAmount()));
        supplierDebtRepository.update(supplierDebt);
        return purchaseInvoiceLine;
    }
}
```

Should `@Transactional` rollback the whole transaction if it fails at the following line (which is not a database operation)?

```
stock.setQuantity(stock.getQuantity().add(purchaseInvoiceLine.getQuantity()));
```

Update:

Because the table "stock" does not have any records, at `// update stock`, the stock object that is read is null, so a `NullPointerException` is thrown at the next line in which it tries to set the quantity. Here's the whole stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.tawila.erpproject.service.impl.SalesInvoiceLineServiceImpl.save(SalesInvoiceLineServiceImpl.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.tawila.erpproject.controller.SalesInvoiceLineController.save(SalesInvoiceLineController.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
```

Comment: Is it somehow important to you bussines logic?

Comment: Given the way `@Transactional` has been applied, yes, the transactional will be rolled back if the line pointed out throws a `RuntimeException` or any of its derived exceptions.

Comment: @Antoniossss yes, I am trying to get it to either run all operations successfully or rollback all of them and it's not working... So, I wanna know if it should roll them all back if it throws an exception at something that doesn't have to do with the database...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will, according to the Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back):

> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. ( Errors will also - by default - result in a rollback). Checked exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default configuration.

Given that your failure criteria is an unchecked exception.

Because you marked the class as `@Transactional`, as you invoke `PurchaseInvoiceLineService.save()` the proxy will start the transaction and if there was any exceptions with the method execution, catch them and rollback the transaction.

Comment: How do I do this? Should I surround the whole method with a try-catch block and roll them back in the catch block? If so, how do I roll them back?

Comment: What I read is that Spring is supposed to take care of all this automatically which does not happen...

Comment: Can you update the question with the stacktrace of the `save()`?

Comment: Alright, enable trace logging or debug and see what is going on here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.java#L514

Answer (score 1):

Depends - if the transaction was already started (implementation/bussiness logic dependent) it will be rolled back - but could be commited as well - with no operations.

Something has to be done with the transaction to release DB connection. Rolling back is the most common solution. More over it is most universal one as it will fit into most scenarios - even with nested and extended transactions.